# Finding kinematic equation with time-varying acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, displacement

I would like to obtain a relation between initial velocity and distance covered till velocity is zero, with time varying acceleration. For a constant acceleration we can solve:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x_0} m  \, a(t) dx &= \frac{1}{2} m v_0^2\\
\end{align*}

What can we do if the acceleration is not constant?

Comment: The equation you have there doesn't make sense.  Those units will not give distance, that is energy.  That can be a step in solving it, but that equation is not distance.

Comment: @JMac those equation will definitely give a relation between distance and velocity . At RHS is velocity and LHS is distance what are you talking about. I mean of course both sides resemble energy but due to it you get relation between required two

Comment: Although if a is time variable it's not possible to integrate but that's a different thing!

Comment: @Utkarshfutous I don't even understand where he got this integration.  He wants to solve for distance but has 0 and $x_0$ as the integral limits, yet those appear nowhere in the equation beside it, but were still unknown :S  It's weird to talk about distance formulas then show a different formula and skip a bunch of steps in deriving an equivalent expression.

Comment: @JMac I think you have misunderstood it, the given equation is work-energy theorem. For sake of understanding just integrate LHS for constant...you will get m*a*x now simplify the equation you will notice that you got nothing but third equation of motion

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the given equation of acceleration $a = f(t)$
2. Now use $ dv/dt = a $ in place of a
3. Take dt to RHS and integrate
4. Integrate again to get relation between x and t
5. Assume t to be parametric variable get the relation between v and x

Comment: this is what I suspected but was hoping for a more direct way

Comment: I don't think there is other way unless you could relate a and distance or distance and time .